# java.lang.NullPointerException (no error message) whenever I sync my project it always fails. This project is created with flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I have download a project from my old pc and tried to run it . but it keep on showing this error  "java.lang.NullPointerException (no error message)" .It's working fine in my old pc.

Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.

> java.lang.NullPointerException (no error message)

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 7s
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...                              8.8s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

And i tried these solution's :

I've deleted .gradle folder from the project.
And Change gradle version.
Uninstalled android studio and tried to match the version my old pc had.
I've deleted pubspec.lock from the project.

Nothing worked for me but in my old pc its still running without any error
but it does not work in other lap or pc.

Answer (score 1):

you can try "flutter clean" and then "flutter build" and then "flutter pub get"

Answer (score 0):

> have you put this in your gradle file

```
 android {
        lintOptions {
            checkReleaseBuilds false
        }
    }
```

Comment: yes tried now and its not working and also i run ./gradlew assembleDebug --warning-mode all in android it gives error > Cannot invoke "java.io.File.exists()" because "parent" is null

Comment: please can you check the old and new version of flutter

Comment: old is 2.2.3 but new is 2.10.3 but i updated on my pc to to new version same as my lap but its not working its only working on my pc

Comment: you mean to say you also update the new version in your old pc..and project is working..?

Comment: yes the project is working in old pc after updated to new version

Comment: have you run flutter doctor..?

Comment: and also run flutter clean

Comment: yes ,tried both of them

Comment: just found out this error is causing by agora_rtc_engine: ^5.0.1 package .After removed it works fine

Comment: is there solution this agora rtc engine problem?